# Invalid number of arguments when calling static method through function reference

Tags: actionscript-3, methods, reference, static

interesting issue for you all.
I have a base class with the variable:

```
protected var dataSource:Function = ProductInfoManager.getFilteredDLC;
```

The method over in ProducInfoManager is:

```
public static function getFilteredDLC(filter:FilterList):Array
{
    //do stuff
}
```

calling dataSource(filter) gives me this error:

```
Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on com.xxx.managers::ProductInfoManager$/getFilteredDLC(). Expected 0, got 1.
```

However, in the same scope, calling:

```
ProductInfoManager.getFilteredDLC(filter);
```

works fine.

What am I doing wrong? I want to have this function variable so that it can be overriden by the constructor of descendents of the class.

Comment: Did you try calling the method with `dataSource.call(this, filter)` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same issue

Comment: Get the same issue if I try ProductInfoManager[dataSource](infoFilter); where dataSource is now the string "getFilteredDLC";

Comment: Eugh, looks like I'm going to have to settle for wrapping the function call in an overridable class function.

Comment: I tried it on a very simple project with `protected var _myFunction:Function = StaticClass.Dring;` and called it with `_myFunction.call(this, "yay");`. It worked...

Comment: I've gone back and retried just running the method directly. That's now causing the same error (or was before I mistakenly thought it wasn't) The method seems to have gone weird. If I give it an argument, it fails at runtime, if I don't give it an argument, it fails at compile time.

Comment: Do you mean ProductManager is the base class when it has a static functio named getFilteredDLC and  ProductInfoManager is a subclass of ProductManager ?

Comment: No, sorry pan "ProductManager" was a miss type on my part. fixed it now. I've solved the problem, the ProductInfoManager was being compiled into a linked swf, so instead of recompiling into the child swf, it was using the old, error filled one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the issue.

I was linking some of this swfs library with another, that other swf used the ProductInfoManager, so instead of compiling the newer version of ProductInfoManager with changes, flash was pulling the old version from the other swf.

Quite frustrating behaviour if you don't know what's going on.